# Error when creating new entry! HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException

Tags: craft3, entry, error, debugging

Any help is appreciated! I just downloaded and setup craft using composer. I went to create my first blog entry, and as soon as I click "New Entry" I get this error. Setup went smoothly and I haven't changed any other files. My index files and entry files are displaying in browser correctly, I'm just unable to create new entry. Thanks in advance!

This is the error I'm getting -->HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
This is my file path --> /entries/blog/31?draftId=18&fresh=1
[System Info and error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4fO6.jpg)